# Build array of keys and values?

Tags: php, arrays

Im trying to build a json array in php with this structure:

```
[{"id":"name last name",
  "id":"name last name",
  "id":"name last name"
}]
```

*where the id key is always a different number, not only id string*

Im trying to do this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){
    //$namesArray[] = array($array[$i]["id"] =>$array[$i]["name"].
    //               " ".$array[$i]["last"]." ".$array[$i]["name"]);

    $namesArray[] = array_fill_keys(
        $array[$i]["id"],
        $array[$i]["name"]." ".
            $array[$i]["last"]." ".
            $array[$i]["name"]
    );
}

echo json_encode($namesArray);
```

With the commented lines I get something like this:

```
[{"id":"name last name"},
 {"id":"name last name"}
]
```

But I dont want that, I want all keys and values in a single array.

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of `$namesArray[] = array_fill_keys($array[$i]["id"], $array[$i]["name"]." ".$array[$i]["last"]." ".$array[$i]["name"]);
` try this `$namesArray[$array[$i]["id"]] = $array[$i]["name"];`

Comment: ```$namesArray[$array[$i]["id"]] = $array[$i]["name"]." ".$array[$i]["last"]." ".$array[$i]["name"]``` then ```json_encode([$namesArray])```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```
// sample data
$array = array(
    array("id" => 1, "name" => "James", "last" => "Last"),
    array("id" => 2, "name" => "Micheal", "last" => "Jackson"),
);

// create empty object (associative array)
$obj = (object) array();

// add key/value pairs to that object
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $obj->$row["id"] = $row["name"] . " " . $row["last"];
}

// wrap object in a single-element array
$result = array($obj);

// output to JSON string
echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "1": "James Last",
        "2": "Micheal Jackson"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep your code clean

```
$array = [];
$array[] = ['id'=>3 , 'name'=>'H', 'last'=>'bensiali' ];
$array[] = ['id'=>4 , 'name'=>'Simon', 'last'=>'Says' ];
$array[] = ['id'=>5 , 'name'=>'Mohammed', 'last'=>'Ali' ];


$val = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
   $val[$value['id']] = sprintf("%s %s" , $value['name'] , $value['last']); 
}

echo json_encode($val);
```

And output will be:

```
{"3":"H bensiali","4":"Simon Says","5":"Mohammed Ali"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use functional approach to fill desired array with [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$array = [
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'name1', 'last' => 'last1'],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'name2', 'last' => 'last2'],
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'name3', 'last' => 'last3'],
];


$newArray = array_reduce($array, function($carry, $item) {
    $carry[$item['id']] = $item["name"]." ".
        $item["last"]." ".
        $item["name"];

    return $carry;
});

var_dump($newArray);
```

And output will be:

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  string(17) "name1 last1 name1"
  [2]=>
  string(17) "name2 last2 name2"
  [3]=>
  string(17) "name3 last3 name3"
}
```